# Why is the first order derivative of a function equal to the Lipschitz constant?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

(edited)

I am learning about the concept of Lipschitz constant and function.

I understand you can write:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x - y|$$

(where M is the Lipschitz constant) and thus:

$$M \ge \dfrac {|f(x) - f(y)|} {|x - y|}$$

Of course I realise this has similarities with:

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)| }{h}$$

Could someone please explain what's the actually proper way mathematically to explain or prove that the Lipschitz constant $M$ is actually the same as the first order derivative of the function $f(x)$ (or is it? and if so under which conditions?).

Comment: yes you are right I should write $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M|x-y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $f$ is defined and continuous on an interval $[a,b]$, and is differentiable on the interior $(a,b)$.

1. If $M$ is a Lipschitz constant, then so is any $N>M$. You might be more interested in that $L:= \sup_{x\in (a,b)} |f'(x)|$ is the optimal Lipschitz constant if it is finite.
2. By mean value theorem for every $x,y\in [a,b]$, $x < y$, there exists some $c\in (x,y)\subseteq (a,b)$ such that
   $$ \left | \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \right | = |f'(c)| \le L.$$
   That is, $L$ is indeed a Lipschitz constant.
3. Without loss of generality let $L>0$. 
   By the definition of supremum, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $(a, b)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f'(x_n)| = L$.
4. For $n\in\mathbb N$, due to differentiability, there exists some $y_n \in (a,b)$ with 
   $$ \left| \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} - f'(x_n) \right | < \frac{1}{n}. $$
   Then, by the (reversed) triangle inequality, it follows
   $$ \left | \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} \right | \ge |f'(x_n)| - \left | \frac{f(y_n) - f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} - f'(x_n) \right |  \to L, $$
   for $n\to\infty$.

   That is, every Lipschitz constant needs to be at least $L$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I don't understand point 3. When you say $0<|f'(x_n)| \to L$ it means $f'(x_n)$ maps to $L$ right? Then $n\in\mathbb N$ is a natural number (1, 2, 3...INF). I don't understand the first equation in 3? Why 1 over some real number would always be greater or equal to the term on the left. thx

Comment: @MarcOurens $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f'(x_n)| = L$. The supremum needs not be attained. The first inequality comes from the definition of differentiability of $f$ at $x_n$. Notice that there $n$ is fixed and $y_n$ is selected / exists due differentiability.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but I really don't get it((( I thought $x_n \in (a,b)$ so what's the meaning of $n$ really in this case? To me it means just any number within the interval (a,b), so it seems $_n$ has a meaning here which I don't grasp.

Comment: @MarcOurens: The set $\{ |f'(x)| \mid x\in (a,b) \}$ is only bounded. It has a supremum $L$, but it may not have a maximum. That is, there may be no $\tilde x\in (a,b)$ such that $|f'(\tilde x)| = L$. However, by the definition of supremum, there is a sequence $x_n\in (a, b)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f'(x_n)| = L$. I will expand that part in the answer.