# Application of the fundamental theorem of Calculus?

Tags: calculus, markov-chains, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\Phi : \{0,1\}^{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of a Markov chain on state space $\{0,1\}^N$ where $$\Phi(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \cos\left(\frac{\pi(2i-1)}{2N}\right)x(i).$$
Starting from any given vector $x \in \{0,1\}^{N}$ the Markov chain can change in a single step by, at most, transposing two adjacent values in the vector. (For those familiar this is the exclusion process on a path of length $N$).

In the book I am reading ([Markov Chains and Mixing Times](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) Page 328) the authors say:

> We have $\left|\Phi\left(X_1\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \leq \pi / N$, since the derivative of $u \mapsto \cos \left(\frac{\pi u}{ 2 N}\right)$ is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2 N}$.

Where $x$ is the initial state of the Markov chain and $X_1$ is the state after taking a single step.

Originally, my thought was that this was achieved by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$f(a)-f(b)=\int_b^a f^{\prime}(t) \,\Bbb d t$$

But I’m starting to thing I’m wrong and I’m not sure how it would work even if I was right. The bounds of integration would then be vectors, and the authors don’t use the derivative of $\Phi$ it self but only the cosine part to get an upper bound. I’m quite confused about what is going on here, I would be grateful if someone could please explain how they were able to get such a bound using the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $j$ and $k$ the two positions on which $X_1$ and $x$ differ which satisfies $|j-k| = 1$ and $X_1(j)-x(j) = x(k)-X_1(k)$ by the interchange condition. Then
$$
\big|\Phi(X_1)-\Phi(x)\big| = \left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2j-1)}{2N}\right)\Big(X_1(j)-x(j)\Big) + \cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2N}\right)\Big(X_1(k)-x(k)\Big)\right|
\le \left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi(2j-1)}{2N}\right)
  - \cos\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{2N}\right)\right|
\le \frac{\pi}{2N}|2(j-k)|
$$
where in the last step we used that the $u \mapsto \cos\left(\frac{\pi u}{2N}\right)$ function is $\big(\pi/(2N)\big)$-Lipschitz because its derivative is bounded by $\pi/(2N)$. From this the claim follows by using $|j-k|=1$.

Comment: Excellent! And because of the interchange condition $|X_1(j)-x(j)| =1 $ if the end points of the edge have exchanged places. Thank you very much for your clear explanation!

Comment: Also I will link [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057823/why-is-the-first-order-derivative-of-a-function-equal-to-the-lipschitz-constant) for clarity about why the first order derivative gives the lipschitz constant